# Getting distinct data using TSQL ( Top 1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which gets data from different tables using LEFT join. I want to pick distinct records ( first one only).

Stored procedure is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[hr_ActionLog_GetList]

    @Action INT = NULL,

    @DateFrom DATETIME = NULL,

    @DateTo DATETIME = NULL,

    @CompanyID INT = NULL,

    @RegistrantID INT = NULL,

    @VacancyID INT = NULL,

    @Language INT = 1

AS

BEGIN



    SELECT AL.[RegistrantID]
  ,[EmployeeID]
  ,AL.[UserID]
  ,[CompanyID]
  ,[VacancyID]
  ,[Action])
  ,[ActionDate],

        RV.Forename,

        RV.Surname,

        RV.Username AS RegistrantUsername,

        E.Forename AS EmployeeForename,

        E.Surname AS EmployeeSurname,

        U.Username,

        CASE

            WHEN @Language = 2 THEN V.JobTitleLang2

            ELSE V.JobTitleLang1

        END AS JobTitle

    FROM dbo.hr_ActionLog AL LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RegistrantsListView RV ON AL.RegistrantID = RV.RegistrantID 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Employees E ON AL.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Users U ON AL.UserID = U.UserID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Companies C ON AL.CompanyID = C.CompanyID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Vacancies V ON AL.VacancyID = V.VacancyID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Companies VC ON V.CompanyID = VC.CompanyID


    WHERE (@Action IS NULL OR AL.Action = @Action)

        AND (@DateFrom IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(AL.ActionDate) >= dbo.DateOnly(@DateFrom))

        AND (@DateTo IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(AL.ActionDate) <= dbo.DateOnly(@DateTo))

        AND (@CompanyID IS NULL OR AL.CompanyID = @CompanyID)

        AND (@RegistrantID IS NULL OR AL.RegistrantID = @RegistrantID)

        AND (@VacancyID IS NULL OR AL.VacancyID = @VacancyID)

    ORDER BY AL.ActionDate DESC 

END
```

sample data

```
1786    16294   15  16321   3   NULL    4   2013-08-03 12:18:08.130 cv  3   cv3@cc.com  asif    hameed  asif@bb.com my company1aa   NULL    NULL
1785    16294   15  16321   3   NULL    4   2013-08-03 12:17:57.797 cv  3   cv3@cc.com  asif    hameed  asif@bb.com my company1aa   NULL    NULL
1784    16293   15  16321   3   NULL    4   2013-08-03 12:17:47.243 cv  2   cv2@cc.com  asif    hameed  asif@cc.com my company1aa   NULL    NULL
1783    16295   15  16321   3   NULL    4   2013-08-03 12:17:40.967 cv  4   cv4@cc.com  asif    hameed  asif@cc.com my company1aa   NULL    NULL
1782    16292   15  16321   3   NULL    4   2013-08-03 12:17:31.953 cv  1   CV1@cc.com  asif    hameed  asif@bb.com my company1aa   NULL    NULL
```

I want to get first record from action log table which is distinct.

Comment: What columns have duplicate values ? SQL2005+: `You could use ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY columns ORDER BY ActionDate DESC) AS RowNum` and `WHERE RowNum=1` .

Comment: Why do you have AL.*? This is not going to give distinct records unless two rows have exact same values. You need to find the columns which have duplicate values based on some condition and then add distinct on top of it and then Select TOP 1.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean how can i do this ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: What columns have duplicate values ? You should add  sample rows and desired output.

Comment: @Nilesh I have removed AL.*, what do i need to do next ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean: all columns have duplicate data. I need to find distinct (first one) registantids by companyId in one year. I want number of times registrant was viewed by company.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Please have a look at sample data added in question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understood your question correct; when you say "I want top get first record which is distinct".
But something like this might help. 
I am still not sure what columns have duplicate values, but you can try this.

```
Select Distinct TOP 1 *  from
( SELECT 
  AL.[RegistrantID]
  ,[EmployeeID]
  ,AL.[UserID]
  ,[CompanyID]
  ,[VacancyID]
  ,[Action])
  ,[ActionDate],

        RV.Forename,

        RV.Surname,

        RV.Username AS RegistrantUsername,

        E.Forename AS EmployeeForename,

        E.Surname AS EmployeeSurname,

        U.Username,

        CASE

            WHEN @Language = 2 THEN V.JobTitleLang2

            ELSE V.JobTitleLang1

        END AS JobTitle

    FROM dbo.hr_ActionLog AL LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RegistrantsListView RV ON AL.RegistrantID = RV.RegistrantID 

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Employees E ON AL.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Users U ON AL.UserID = U.UserID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Companies C ON AL.CompanyID = C.CompanyID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Vacancies V ON AL.VacancyID = V.VacancyID

        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Companies VC ON V.CompanyID = VC.CompanyID


    WHERE (@Action IS NULL OR AL.Action = @Action)

        AND (@DateFrom IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(AL.ActionDate) >= dbo.DateOnly(@DateFrom))

        AND (@DateTo IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(AL.ActionDate) <= dbo.DateOnly(@DateTo))

        AND (@CompanyID IS NULL OR AL.CompanyID = @CompanyID)

        AND (@RegistrantID IS NULL OR AL.RegistrantID = @RegistrantID)

        AND (@VacancyID IS NULL OR AL.VacancyID = @VacancyID)

    ORDER BY AL.ActionDate DESC )  subquery
```

You can even add Distinct inside the subquery and just select TOP 1 * in the main select

Comment: Hi @Nilesh: I think i need data distinct by date. Only one row per year. how can i do this ? All values are different in all rows, means now two rows are exact identical.

Answer (score 0):

As @@BogdanSahlean suggested you can try following

```
Select * from

( SELECT 
  AL.[RegistrantID]
  ,[EmployeeID]
  ,AL.[UserID]
  ,[CompanyID]
  ,[VacancyID]
  ,[Action])
  ,[ActionDate],

    RV.Forename,

    RV.Surname,

    RV.Username AS RegistrantUsername,

    E.Forename AS EmployeeForename,

    E.Surname AS EmployeeSurname,

    U.Username,

    CASE

        WHEN @Language = 2 THEN V.JobTitleLang2

        ELSE V.JobTitleLang1

    END AS JobTitle,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(yy,YOURDATEHERE) ORDER BY YOURDATEHERE DESC) ROW

FROM dbo.hr_ActionLog AL LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RegistrantsListView RV ON AL.RegistrantID = RV.RegistrantID 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Employees E ON AL.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Users U ON AL.UserID = U.UserID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Companies C ON AL.CompanyID = C.CompanyID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Vacancies V ON AL.VacancyID = V.VacancyID

    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.hr_Companies VC ON V.CompanyID = VC.CompanyID


WHERE (@Action IS NULL OR AL.Action = @Action)

    AND (@DateFrom IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(AL.ActionDate) >= dbo.DateOnly(@DateFrom))

    AND (@DateTo IS NULL OR dbo.DateOnly(AL.ActionDate) <= dbo.DateOnly(@DateTo))

    AND (@CompanyID IS NULL OR AL.CompanyID = @CompanyID)

    AND (@RegistrantID IS NULL OR AL.RegistrantID = @RegistrantID)

    AND (@VacancyID IS NULL OR AL.VacancyID = @VacancyID)

ORDER BY AL.ActionDate DESC )  subquery
where subquery.Row = 1
```